# LERP Smooth Scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, linear-interpolation

I have been wanting to implement smooth scrolling in vanilla JS for some time, but could not find any adequate implementations or methods. However, I recently came across the concept of linear interpolation (LERP), which seems adequate unlike every other method.

Although content about LERP smooth scrolling seems scarce on the web, I just found two great articles ([one](https://codepen.io/rachsmith/post/animation-tip-lerp), [two](https://codepen.io/rachsmith/post/how-to-move-elements-on-scroll-in-a-way-that-doesn-t-suck-too-bad)) about LERP in general and an [example](https://codepen.io/nickalcantara/pen/NJGVom?editors=1111) of LERP being used for smooth scrolling on codepen.

The example, notably, seems unnecessarily complex due to a seemingly unnecessary amount of nested containers, so I created a [minimal version](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/eYzXaRx) of it shown below. The minimal version seems to be working, but I still have a few concerns and questions.

```js
const
  b = document.body,
  m = document.querySelector('main'),
  p = document.querySelector('p')

let
  state = {
    scroll: {
      height: 0,
      offset: 0,
      speed: 0.075,
    }
  },
  direction

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  state.scroll.height = m.getBoundingClientRect().height
  b.style.height = `${Math.floor(state.scroll.height)}px`
})

b.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  direction = e.deltaY > 0 ? 'scrollDown' : 'scrollUp'
  // renderLoop()
})

function renderLoop() {
  // const
  //   difference = 'scrollDown' ? pageYOffset - state.scroll.offset : state.scroll.offset - pageYOffset
  state.scroll.offset += Math.floor((pageYOffset - state.scroll.offset) * state.scroll.speed)
  m.style.transform = `translateY(-${ state.scroll.offset }px)`
  // if (difference > 20) requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop)
  requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop)
}

renderLoop()
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
border: solid green 3px; box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
border: solid red 3px; box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>One<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error soluta, quidem voluptatibus quo iusto iure adipisci, ullam quis unde dolore, nisi impedit in. Veniam, suscipit? Atque aut et incidunt aliquid. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem labore dolore aut atque harum, quo necessitatibus molestias laborum fuga beatae explicabo laudantium asperiores doloremque optio iure, assumenda voluptate unde voluptates? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet inventore, voluptates corrupti illo impedit in. Recusandae, praesentium temporibus tempore totam cupiditate ratione maxime numquam corporis repudiandae. Veniam ullam rerum quo?</p>
  <p>Two<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error soluta, quidem voluptatibus quo iusto iure adipisci, ullam quis unde dolore, nisi impedit in. Veniam, suscipit? Atque aut et incidunt aliquid. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem labore dolore aut atque harum, quo necessitatibus molestias laborum fuga beatae explicabo laudantium asperiores doloremque optio iure, assumenda voluptate unde voluptates? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet inventore, voluptates corrupti illo impedit in. Recusandae, praesentium temporibus tempore totam cupiditate ratione maxime numquam corporis repudiandae. Veniam ullam rerum quo?</p>
  <p>Three<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error soluta, quidem voluptatibus quo iusto iure adipisci, ullam quis unde dolore, nisi impedit in. Veniam, suscipit? Atque aut et incidunt aliquid. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem labore dolore aut atque harum, quo necessitatibus molestias laborum fuga beatae explicabo laudantium asperiores doloremque optio iure, assumenda voluptate unde voluptates? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet inventore, voluptates corrupti illo impedit in. Recusandae, praesentium temporibus tempore totam cupiditate ratione maxime numquam corporis repudiandae. Veniam ullam rerum quo?</p>
</main>
```

**One concern is that for some reason it breaks unless I call `renderLoop` from the global scope and let `requestAnimationFrame` run indefinitely without a killswitch, which, instinctively, does not seem like a good idea?**

I am also confused by the fact that, although I am offsetting the content container via `translate`, there still appears to be a scrollbar that scrolls. And yet, notably, this does not appear to interfere with the effect at all. **However, should LERP smooth scrolling via `translate` not bypass scrollbars and scrolling altogether?**

Additionally, it seems as though the only purpose of setting the `height` of `body` to that of `main` is to make use of `pageYOffset`. I suspect there are better ways to approach the problem that do not involve using `pageYOffset`. **Further, you would think that the combination of offsetting with `translate` and the page being scrolled would increase the rate at which the content is scrolled?**

**Anyways, I have just started coding again after an almost year-long absence, and I am not sure if I ever familiarized myself with `requestAnimationFrame`, so any information, guidance, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.**

[ edit + update ]

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/eYzoeBY) of a "working" (?) version, which can be seen below, that I created in attempt to address and solve some concerns or issues present in the version above. However, it clearly does not have the same effect due to, I believe, the offset value being a percentage instead of pixels, which was chosen in an attempt to standardize the "speed" at which it scrolls across "platforms" (i.e. devices, browsers, etc).

```js
const
  b = document.body,
  m = document.querySelector('main')

let
  scrollState = {
    overflow: 0,
    target: 0,
    position: 0,
    rate: 10,
    speed: 0.2
  }

b.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
  scrollState.target -= scrollState.rate * (e.deltaY / 100)
  if (scrollState.target > 0) scrollState.target = 0
  else if (scrollState.target < -100) scrollState.target = -100
  renderLoop()
})

function renderLoop() {
  const
    rawDiff = Math.abs(scrollState.position - scrollState.target),
    direction = scrollState.position - scrollState.target < 0 ? -1 : 1,
    diff = rawDiff * scrollState.speed * direction,
    newPosition = scrollState.position - diff

  m.style.transform = `translateY(${newPosition}%)`
  scrollState.position = newPosition
  if (Math.floor(rawDiff)) requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop)
}
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
border: solid blue 4px; box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
border: solid green 2px; box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
border: solid red 2px; box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>One<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error soluta, quidem voluptatibus quo iusto iure adipisci, ullam quis unde dolore, nisi impedit in. Veniam, suscipit? Atque aut et incidunt aliquid. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem labore dolore aut atque harum, quo necessitatibus molestias laborum fuga beatae explicabo laudantium asperiores doloremque optio iure, assumenda voluptate unde voluptates? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet inventore, voluptates corrupti illo impedit in. Recusandae, praesentium temporibus tempore totam cupiditate ratione maxime numquam corporis repudiandae. Veniam ullam rerum quo?</p>
  <p>Two<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error soluta, quidem voluptatibus quo iusto iure adipisci, ullam quis unde dolore, nisi impedit in. Veniam, suscipit? Atque aut et incidunt aliquid. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem labore dolore aut atque harum, quo necessitatibus molestias laborum fuga beatae explicabo laudantium asperiores doloremque optio iure, assumenda voluptate unde voluptates? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet inventore, voluptates corrupti illo impedit in. Recusandae, praesentium temporibus tempore totam cupiditate ratione maxime numquam corporis repudiandae. Veniam ullam rerum quo?</p>
  <p>Three<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Error soluta, quidem voluptatibus quo iusto iure adipisci, ullam quis unde dolore, nisi impedit in. Veniam, suscipit? Atque aut et incidunt aliquid. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem labore dolore aut atque harum, quo necessitatibus molestias laborum fuga beatae explicabo laudantium asperiores doloremque optio iure, assumenda voluptate unde voluptates? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet inventore, voluptates corrupti illo impedit in. Recusandae, praesentium temporibus tempore totam cupiditate ratione maxime numquam corporis repudiandae. Veniam ullam rerum quo?</p>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

@oldboy, I'm having the same issue regarding the scarcity of LERP + smooth scrolling on the web. Nevertheless, here is a slightly different approach involving **smooth vertical scroll** + **LERP** with a **kill switch**. It might not be perfect yet but it could be the building block to expand upon.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');
const track = document.querySelector('.slider-track');
let startY = 0;
let endY = 0;
let raf;

const lerp = (start,end,t) => start * (1-t) + end * t;

function update() {
  startY = lerp(startY,endY,0.05);
  track.style.transform = `translateY(-${startY}px)`;
  raf = requestAnimationFrame(update);
  if (startY.toFixed(1) === slider.scrollTop.toFixed(1)) cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
}

function move() {
  endY = slider.scrollTop; 
  cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
  raf = requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

window.addEventListener('load',update,false);
slider.addEventListener('scroll',move,false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: min(600px,90vw);
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.slider-track {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.slider-item {
  width: inherit;
  height: 70vh;
  border: 0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font: 900 0.85rem helvetica,sans-serif;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar       { width: 1rem; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track { border-left: 0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { 
  border: 0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<main class='slider'>
  <div class='slider-track'>
    <div class='slider-item'>1</div>
    <div class='slider-item'>2</div>
    <div class='slider-item'>3</div>
    <div class='slider-item'>4</div>
    <div class='slider-item'>5</div>
    <div class='slider-item'>6</div>
    <div class='slider-item'>7</div>
    <div class='slider-item'>8</div>
    <div class='slider-item'>9</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Overview:

1. create a function to run the **LERP** formula

> const lerp = (start,end,t) => start * (1-t) + end * t;

2. when our project "load", do the following:

   a) invoke the callback "update" & update the starting y-position aka "startY" with "lerp". "0.05" is the "easing" which can range from "0.01 to "0.99"

   > startY = lerp(startY,endY,0.05);

   b) move our slider's "track" vertically with "translateY" + negative "startY" in pixels

   > track.style.transform = `translateY(-${startY}px)`;

   c) invoke "update" recursively with "requestAnimationFrame" and store it in "raf"

   > raf = requestAnimationFrame(update);

   d) if "startY" is equal to "slider.scrollTop" to the nearest tenths then cancel "raf" (kill switch)

   > if (startY.toFixed(1) === slider.scrollTop.toFixed(1)) cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
3. lastly, whenever the "scroll" event is trigged on "slider" then:

   a) invoke the callback "move" & track the current y-position aka "endY" with the "scrollTop" property on "slider"

   > endY = slider.scrollTop;

   b) cancel "raf" (kill switch)

   > cancelAnimationFrame(raf);

   c) invoke "update" recursively with "requestAnimationFrame"

   > raf = requestAnimationFrame(update);

Please do drop me a comment when you improve upon this approach or your own code, I like to check'em out :)

Comment: Upvote based solely on the demo. When I get some time to begin coding again and really test this out, I will mark whether or not it answers the question. Thanks for sharing!